# Update dynamically TextView value with AlertDialog input

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I have a Textview id in many layout in my app. When the alertDialog appear to user, I want that value entered by him update Textview value.
I have tried the code below but when I'm going in others layout, the TextView is not update.

Please give me a solution.

```
       mlnCurrency = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lncurrency);


    mlnCurrency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           mtvdevicelabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdevicelabel);



                                           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingActivity.this);
                                           builder.setTitle("Title");

                                           final EditText input = new EditText(SettingActivity.this);

                                           input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                                           builder.setView(input);


                                           builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                   m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                                                   mtvdevicelabel.setText(m_Text );
                                               }
                                           });
                                           builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                   dialog.cancel();
                                               }
                                           });

                                           builder.show();


                                       }
                                   }
    );
```

Comment: That's because the view you are using just containts one of the TextViews that you are trying to update. The rest of them are in others views.

Comment: @JonathanAste What is this 'others views'? Please explain: "when I'm going in others layout"...

Comment: @Aristide.. could u plz upload screen shot, so that we have better understanding

Comment: In your fragment you just have the layout inflated in onCreate method, so you will be able to work only with views inside that layout

Comment: Just to explain : Imagine an app which contain a currency symbol. The countries have defferent currency symbol. So I need to show to the user an alertertdialog where he should able to update her symbole. So all Layouts will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your fragment run in other UIThread totally diferent from your Activity, you should use the delegate pattern calling the delegateMethod when you update your text. Also you could use EventBus or Otto for this, or RxJava for android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        changeName();
                }
        );


public void changeName()

{

//DO update
}
```

Comment: Still not ok, the layout is update one time but when I'm giong others layout. No update done.

Comment: are you using a ListView or something like this?

Comment: No, I have my TextView in a LinearLayout